# Web NDEFReader как считать тег

Tags: javascript, html

Есть NFC метка с записанным текстом внутри. Как считать этот текст в Web NDEFReader?

Код:

```
NDEF.scan().then(() => {
  NDEF.onreading = event => {
    var msg = event.message;
    for (var data of msg.records) {
      alert(Тут должен быть текст)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Отвечаю на собственный вопрос:

```
NDEF.scan().then(() => {
  NDEF.onreading = event => {
    var msg = event.message;
    for (var records of msg.records) {
      var textDecoder = new TextDecoder();
      console.log(textDecoder.decode(records.data));
    }
  }
}
```

Через цикл for мы вывели содержимое объекта records. `records.data` это содержимое записи, но НЕТ! `records.data` это тоже объект, но он не содержит методов. Его нужно декодировать через `TextDecoder()`. Пользуйтесь те, кто собирается делать Web NFC.